# From Python to Java how can I do hex escape sequences?

Tags: java, python, hex

I'm trying to control a relay board via Socket commands.

I was able to make a small Python program that works fine:

```
import socket
HOST = '192.168.1.1'
PORT = 5000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
DATA = '\x58\x01\x12\x00\x00\x00\x05\x70'
s.send(DATA)
data = s.recv(4096)
s.close()
d = data.encode('hex').upper()
print 'Received', repr(d)
```

And now I would like to switch it to Java but I'm having a problem on sending the HEX string that I know in java should be written as:
0x58, 0x01, 0x12........
Can Anybody help me to convert this few line in a Java routine that works?

Comment: Post what you've tried so far and we may spot mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

In Java if you write `String command = ("0x58, 0x01, 0x12, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x6F");`, `command` will be a string containing just the characters you entered. What you need to do instead if to use a `byte` array and then initialize your string using that byte array. Something like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[]{
    (byte)0x58,
    (byte)0x01, 
    (byte)0x12, 
    (byte)0x00, 
    (byte)0x00, 
    (byte)0x00, 
    (byte)0x04, 
    (byte)0x6F
};

BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
String command = new String(buffer);
wr.write(command);
System.out.println(command);

// Flushing the writer
wr.flush();
```